# How to stick a Xib to the top of the IphoneX

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, xib, iphone-x

I Created a Xib file and link it with a UIView subclass.

I use the code below :

```
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SmartRemoteConnectedBanner", owner: self, options: nil)

    contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}
```

It works perfectly with standard iPhones, but I don't manage to stick it to the top of the IphoneX.

Comment: You cannot set an anchor and also use autoresizing. You use autolayout or autoresizing, not both.

Comment: I observe that you have asked 8 questions and have NEVER _accepted_ an answer. Answer acceptance is the coin of the realm on Stack Overflow. No one has any incentive to help you if you do not accept answers. Please go back over your old questions and consider this situation. For questions with no answers, think about how the question falls short of SO requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set constraint to the superview, not to the SafeArea which is smaller in iPhoneX. You can also extend the SafeArea.
[Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area)

```
var newSafeArea = UIEdgeInsets()
   // Adjust the safe area to accommodate 
   //  the height of the bottom view.
   if let bottomViewHeight = bottomView?.bounds.size.height {
      newSafeArea.bottom += bottomViewHeight
   }
   // Adjust the safe area insets of the 
   //  embedded UIView.
   contentView.additionalSafeAreaInsets = newSafeArea
}
```